# Make a button image change when pressed / focused / disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several pictures of the same button, each one representing it in a different sate: normal, pressed, focused, disabled.

How can I make it into an html button that automatically shows the correct picture (and also has an onClick event) ?

Feel free to use html / css / javascript.

The tag also doesn't need to be a button, it could be an image, , or whatever you want, but hopefully written in a generic enough way for others to use your solution too

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: SO isnt code service.

Comment: Oh, wow, sorry :( I'm actually doing something much more specific (creating a Google sign in button that authenticates with Firebase, using React components), but my current button handling doesn't seem like best-practice at all (Iv'e done tons of c++ in my career, but this is my first web project). Since I didn't find a best practice solution for this very generic sounding problem (a button that changes picture), I posted this question. No problem, I can post a new question with a complete example of my current (React) code, (though I think it would be less useful for the community) @obsidian

Answer (score 2):

Just add a class to a link:

```
<a href="#" class='styledbutton'>Buttontext</a>
```

... and some CSS:

```
.styledbutton {background: url(defaultstate.png); display: inline-block;}
.styledbutton:hover {background: url(hoverstate.png);}
.styledbutton:focus {background: url(focusstate.png);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the CSS pseudo-selectors [**`:hover`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and [**`:focus`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) to change the state of a button at various different interaction points, and simply tie a function into the [**`onclick`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event in order to run additional JavaScript if required:

```js
function buttonClick() {
  console.log('Button clicked');
}
```

```css
button { /* Default state */
  background: white;
}

button:hover { /* On hover */
  background: red;
}

button:focus { /* After a click */
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonClick()">Button</button>
```

Keep in mind that this can also be done with an image by simply passing the image's path into [**`background-image`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) as a `url()` value.

Comment: [SO isn't a code service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601739/make-a-button-image-change-when-pressed-focused-disabled#comment78162914_45601739) but you respond anyway?

Comment: @Daedalus -- I have **literally** nothing better to do at the moment, and thought this answer might at least help a few people :)

Comment: Very well.  I'm surprised there doesn't immediately appear to be a duplicate target which would serve the purpose better.